dplyr returning NA in new column and not following conditions
I have one data frame about animal sightings (more than 300), with species of whales, dolphins, pinipedes and penguins.
And I want to create a new column reino, which would be misticeto for whales, odontoceto for dolphins, pinipede for pinipedes and penguin for penguins.
But when I do that, one specific whale (Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis)) result in NA value at reino column.
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.1.4’


dt = data.table(especie= c('Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis)','Ballena barbada no identificada (Parvorden Mysticeti)', 'Ballena jorobada (Megaptera novaeangliae)', 'Ballena rorcual no identificada (Balaenoptera sp.)', 'Ballena sei (Balaenoptera borealis)', 'Ballena fin (Balaenoptera physalus)', 'Ballena barbada no identificada(Parvorden Mysticeti)','Delfín austral (Lagenorhynchus australis)', 'Delfín no identificado (Familia Delphinidae)', 'Tonina overa (Cephalorhynchus commersonii)', 'Delfín oscuro (Lagenorhynchus obscurus)','Lobo marino de dos pelos no identificado (Arctocephalus sp.)', 'Lobo marino no identificado (Familia Otariidae)', 'Lobo marino de dos pelos sudamericano (Arctocephalus australis)', 'Lobo marino de un pelo sudamericano (Otaria flavescens)', 'Lobo marino de dos pelos antártico (Arctocephalus gazella)','Lobo marino de dos pelos sudamericano (Arctocephalusaustralis)','Pingüino patagónico (Spheniscus magellanicus)', 'Pingüino no identificado (Familia Spheniscidae)', 'Cormorán Imperial (Phalacrocorax albiventer)', 'Pingüino penacho amarillo austral (Eudyptes chrysocome)', 'Pingüino rey (Aptenodytes patagonicus)'))

as.character(dt$especie)


I want do do this:
dt$reino[dt$especie %in% c('Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis)','Ballena barbada no identificada (Parvorden Mysticeti)', 'Ballena jorobada (Megaptera novaeangliae)', 'Ballena rorcual no identificada (Balaenoptera sp.)', 'Ballena sei (Balaenoptera borealis)', 'Ballena fin (Balaenoptera physalus)', 'Ballena barbada no identificada(Parvorden Mysticeti)')] <- 'misticeto'

dt$reino[dt$especie %in% c('Delfín austral (Lagenorhynchus australis)', 'Delfín no identificado (Familia Delphinidae)', 'Tonina overa (Cephalorhynchus commersonii)', 'Delfín oscuro (Lagenorhynchus obscurus)')] <- 'odontoceto'

dt$reino[dt$especie %in% c('Lobo marino de dos pelos no identificado (Arctocephalus sp.)', 'Lobo marino no identificado (Familia Otariidae)', 'Lobo marino de dos pelos sudamericano (Arctocephalus australis)', 'Lobo marino de un pelo sudamericano (Otaria flavescens)', 'Lobo marino de dos pelos antártico (Arctocephalus gazella)','Lobo marino de dos pelos sudamericano (Arctocephalusaustralis)')] <- 'pinipede'

dt$reino[dt$especie %in% c('Pingüino patagónico (Spheniscus magellanicus)', 'Pingüino no identificado (Familia Spheniscidae)', 'Cormorán Imperial (Phalacrocorax albiventer)', 'Pingüino penacho amarillo austral (Eudyptes chrysocome)', 'Pingüino rey (Aptenodytes patagonicus)')] <- 'penguin'


When I run the code for the first time came this warning:
Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised column: reino. 
Then, I continue running the code, and the new column reino came with NA value only for Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis).
I tried to do these things, but didn't work:
dt %>% left_join(data.frame(especie = c('Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis)', reino = c('misticeto'))))

and

mutate(reino = case_match(especie, 'Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis)' ~ 'misticeto'))

The second problem is that:

I noticed that one dolphin and one penguin came to the misticeto (whale) condition.

misticeto<-filter(dt, reino == "misticeto");misticeto

> table(misticeto$especie)

Ballena barbada no identificada (Parvorden Mysticeti)  Ballena barbada no identificada(Parvorden Mysticeti) 
                                                   23                                                     1 
                  Ballena fin (Balaenoptera physalus)          Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis) 
                                                    4                                                    33 
            Ballena jorobada (Megaptera novaeangliae)    Ballena rorcual no identificada (Balaenoptera sp.) 
                                                   13                                                     9 
                  Ballena sei (Balaenoptera borealis)               Delfín oscuro (Lagenorhynchus obscurus) 
                                                    8                                                     1 
               Pingüino rey (Aptenodytes patagonicus) 
                                                    1 

#The Delfín oscuro (Lagenorhynchus obscurus) and Pingüino rey (Aptenodytes patagonicus)  shouldn't be there.


And also, not all dolphins are going to the reino column, one is missing (who came to misticeto condition).

odontocetos<-filter(dt, reino == "odontoceto");odontocetos
> table(odontocetos$especie)

   Delfín austral (Lagenorhynchus australis) Delfín no identificado (Familia Delphinidae) 
                                          25                                           12 
  Tonina overa (Cephalorhynchus commersonii) 
                                           8 

#The dolphin that came to misticeto condition is missing here, 'Delfín oscuro (Lagenorhynchus obscurus)'

Someone can help me, please? I don't understand what is happening.
Thanks!
UPDATE
I run this, but the dtthat was data frame, was converted to formula
dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(reino = case_when(especie %in% c('Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis)','Ballena barbada no identificada (Parvorden Mysticeti)','Ballena barbada no identificada(Parvorden Mysticeti)', 'Ballena fin (Balaenoptera physalus)','Ballena jorobada (Megaptera novaeangliae)', 'Ballena rorcual no identificada (Balaenoptera sp.)','Ballena sei (Balaenoptera borealis)') ~ 'misticeto', 
                           
                           especie %in% c('Delfín austral (Lagenorhynchus australis)', 'Delfín no identificado (Familia Delphinidae)', 'Delfín oscuro (Lagenorhynchus obscurus)', 'Tonina overa (Cephalorhynchus commersonii)') ~ 'odontoceto',
                           
                           especie %in% c('Lobo marino de dos pelos antártico (Arctocephalus gazella)', 'Lobo marino de dos pelos no identificado (Arctocephalus sp.)', 'Lobo marino de dos pelos sudamericano (Arctocephalus australis)', 'Lobo marino de dos pelos sudamericano (Arctocephalusaustralis)', 'Lobo marino de un pelo sudamericano (Otaria flavescens)') ~ 'pinipede',
                           
                           especie %in% c('Cormorán Imperial (Phalacrocorax albiventer)', 'Pingüino no identificado (Familia Spheniscidae)', 'Pingüino patagónico (Spheniscus magellanicus)', 'Pingüino penacho amarillo austral (Eudyptes chrysocome)','Pingüino rey (Aptenodytes patagonicus)'))) ~ 'pinguin'

> class(dt)
[1] "formula"


I also tried this below, and that whale still not work
misticeto <- filter (dt, especie %in% c('Ballena barbada no identificada (Parvorden Mysticeti)','Ballena barbada no identificada(Parvorden Mysticeti)', 'Ballena fin (Balaenoptera physalus)','Ballena jorobada (Megaptera novaeangliae)', 'Ballena rorcual no identificada (Balaenoptera sp.)','Ballena sei (Balaenoptera borealis)','Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis)'))


More help, please?

Maybe focussing on the obvious first, the warning message comes from subsetting a variable that isn't there, namely dt$reino. You can assign output to it like so dt$reino <- dt$especie[something]. Btw, why use data.table for those strings? The benefit of using it on a data set of 300 is probably negligible.

I like Ronak's case_when() solution but for a situation like this I'd rather have a separate 2 column data.frame with the mapping and use a left join.

Andre, my data is data.frame, and I tried this your code, but didn't work. and Moody, what do you mean to separate 2 column with mapping and use left join?

I just updated the text with the new code that I tried.

The reason you get the first warning is because you are assigning the value to a column which does not exist (reino). Since you are using dplyr one way to do this is with case_when/case_match.
library(dplyr)

dt <- dt %>%
  mutate(reino = case_when(especie %in% c('Ballena franca austral (Eubalaena australis)','Ballena barbada.....') ~ 'misticeto', 
                           especie %in% c('Delfín austral (Lagenorhynchus australis)', 'Delfín no...') ~ 'odontoceto',
                           ......
                           ))

dt

I have marked the long text with ... which you can fill in with your data. You need to ensure that the words match exactly as you have them in your data. If you want to use data.table it has got a function called fcase which behaves in the same way.

I ran the code with dt (data frame), but didn't create a new column, removed the dt (data frame) and created/convertet to Values. What it could be?. class(dt) [1] "formula"
